# Editable ComboBox will not allow writing

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a ComboBox with property `IsEditable=true` created using the following code:

```
ComboBox buffer = new ComboBox()
{
        BorderBrush = null,
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
        Background = null,
        FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Semilight"),
        FontSize = 24,
        IsEditable = true,
        IsTextSearchEnabled = true,
        IsTextSearchCaseSensitive = false,
        StaysOpenOnEdit = true,
};
```

It is added in a WrapPanel in a ScrollViewer defined like this :

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="582,107,142,240" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Height="226" Width="357">
        <Border Background="White" 
                CornerRadius="10" 
                BorderBrush="Black" 
                BorderThickness="1" 
                MouseDown="Border_MouseDown" 
                MouseLeave="Border_MouseLeave" 
                MouseUp="Border_MouseUp">
            <WrapPanel x:Name="sourcesWrapPanel" Width="357"/>
        </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

It works fine when selecting manually but writing will not work (pressing the keys does not input any text). The only thing that works is selecting an item using the mouse or the up/down arrows then deleting characters in it using backspace. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for [ComboBox.IsEditable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1):

[image]

I think you need to set `ComboBox.IsReadOnly` to `false`.

Comment: By default ComboBox.IsReadOnly is set to false.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation snapshot but I had already tried that without success alas. :/ The `IsReadOnly` property is also `false` by default, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The `e.Handled` was set to `true` in the parent control so only the `PreviewKeyDown`handler was executed for the child (`ComboBox`) which is why I could only delete text or paste it but not write any.